# JS library to check if extra data field returned in http response payload?

Tags: javascript, http, testing

I’m currently working on building end-to-end testing for an API another team is working on, and I was wondering if anyone perhaps knows about a JS library that I could use to test whether an extra field is returned in HTTP response body? The purpose of this functionality would be to keep the QA team informed when the dev team makes changes to the api via the tests, instead of the developers manually having to let us know they’ve created updates. I know this can be implemented manually but if the wheel already exists, I’d prefer to avoid recreating it lol.

Example scenario:

API call: GET user
    - returns : user name, user ID and user birthday.

With proposed functionality, if the dev team made updates to the Get user call, and it returns the following
   - return  : user name, user ID, user birthday AND user address.

A test would fail to let me know that an extra field that wasn't expected (user address) was returned.

Comment: Are you able to use the `Fetch` web API ? It should have everything you need to do this, if possible :)

Comment: While it's a relatively interesting question, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow (we don't do shopping recommendations); it may be a good fit for [softwarerecs.se] though, but do check their FAQ/help pages first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema validation seems to be what you are looking for. Besides the library mentioned in another answer, you may also want check a similar one: [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi)

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  userName: Joi.string().alphanum().required(),
  userId: Joi.number().required(),
  userBirthDay: Joi.number().required(),
})

const result = Joi.validate({
  userName: 'johndoe',
  userId: 1234567,
  userBirthDay: 1970,
  userAddress: 'John Doe St.'
}, schema);

if (result.error) {
  console.log(result.error.details);
}
```

In the spec you can make assertion on existence of `error` key in `result` object using the assertion library of your choice.
The example above assumes that you are using nodejs as an environment to run tests, but browser version of joi also exists: [joi-browser](https://github.com/jeffbski/joi-browser)

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't heard much about this topic, but I went with what you said, did some research and found exactly the tool I needed. :D

Comment: @star98 My pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

You need schema validation, there are libraries out there like [ajv](https://ajv.js.org).

```js
var ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true }); // options can be passed, e.g. {allErrors: true}
// API call: GET user - returns : user name, user ID and user birthday.
// With proposed functionality, if the dev team made updates to the Get user call, and it returns the following - return : user name, user ID, user birthday AND user address.
var schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    userName: {
      type: "string",
    },
    userId: {
      type: "string",
    },
    userBirthdate: {
      type: "string",
    },
  },
  required: ["userName", "userId", "userBirthdate"],
  additionalProperties: false,
};
var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
var validUser = {
  userName: "John",
  userId: "john",
  userBirthdate: "01012000",
};
var invalidUser = {
  userName: "John",
  userId: "john",
  userBirthdate: "01012000",
  userAddress: "World",
};
var valid = validate(validUser);
console.log(`Valid user is valid: ${valid}`);
valid = validate(invalidUser);
console.log(`Invalid user is valid: ${valid}`);
console.log('Validate errors:', validate.errors);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/6.6.2/ajv.min.js"></script>
```